# Response being read as an error in subscription

Tags: c#, angular, api

I'm sending a text reponse on from an API but the angular 10 subscription is reading it as an error when it is not failing.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, the desired response is coming through and being understood in angulars subscription handler as an error when it is not an error.

**EDIT 2**
Finally an error after restarting VS
[image]

In postman the status is coming back as two hundred Ok. Console log never hits success but the success response is coming through as an error. What have I done wrong?

**Angular service:**

```
  startSession(session: Session) {
    let sessionForStart = new StartDto(session); // simple mapping so as not take all properties
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/start', sessionForStart);
  }
```

**Angular:**

```
  startSession(session: Session) {
    const options = {
// some option stuff for dialog removed for brevity
    };

    this.dialog.open(options);

    this.dialog.confirmed().subscribe((confirmed) => {
      if (confirmed) {
        this.sessionService.startSession(session)
            .subscribe(
              data => console.log(data),
              error => this.toastr.error(error)
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

**API:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> StartSession(Dto dto) 
{
    try
    {
        string sessionResult = await sessionControllerControls.StartSessionController(dto);
            return Ok(sessionResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            $"Starting failed with the following exception:\n{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: console.log the error to identify what is failing.

Comment: That's the issue, it isn't failing, the correct response is coming through as an error. Updated the question for clarity.

Comment: is the code in `sessionService.startSession(session)` straight forward or do you have any response manipulation in it.?

Comment: I'll upidate the Q but fairly straight  forward.

Comment: try setting your response code to 200 for example and see what you get

Comment: So, what does `error` contain? This looks like it should just work, if not, this code doesn't reproduce the problem. Start by reading [ask] and how to create a [mre].

Comment: The correct response. Which is what's strumped me, the string is coming through as an error. If I log out error.error.message then the correct response is displayed logged out as an error.

Comment: The code is ending up in `error` for _some_ reason. We can't see your data nor your console, so we can't answer this for you.

Comment: @PurpleSmurph the error instance is an wrapper over your response. what else does it give. response code may be?

Comment: is your response a valid json object?

Comment: try setting {headers:reqHeader, responseType: 'myResponseType'} in your post function

Comment: Thank you people, restarted VS and it's behaving differently, does appear to be an error as well as the correct response.

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive text from your api, not a json. This is what the error means (unexpected token 'S' at position 0...).
You can tell the http expect a certain response type, e.g. text:

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/start', sessionForStart, {responseType: 'text'});
```

Comment: Thanks, was just looking at the API, would it be best to send JSON from the API instead as `JsonResult` ?

Comment: I'm not well-versed enough in .net to tell you how to properly send out the response as a json. I think in your case `await sessionControllerControls.StartSessionController(dto)` returns a text. Maybe you can ask another question for this topic. cheers.